# How to use props in ES5 React native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I am using ES5 standard and I don't know how to use props in ES5.Please help me and please do share snippet....

```
const SharePhotoPage= React.createClass({

    render() {

        return (
                <View >
                </View>
        );
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use React.createClass instead of ES6 class, you should call getInitialState() to init state and pass props to it. For example:

```
    var Header = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            title: this.props.title
        };
    },
});
```

Cheer!